# What is the correct way to bind a DataGrid to XML in MVVM?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, binding

I would like to bind a DataGrid to an XML file, that can be updated / changed via two-way binding.

Currently, the source doesn't change when updated.

I have attempted to build it using the following code:

XAML

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ItemsSource="{Binding CFCCDataView.DataView, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

ViewModel

```
public XMLCFCCTranslationList CFCCDataView { get; set; }

public VM()
{
CFCCDataView = new XMLCFCCTranslationList();
}
```

Model

```
    class XMLCFCCTranslationList : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private DataView _dataView;
        public DataView DataView
        {
            get => _dataView;
            set
            {
                if (_dataView == value) return;
                _dataView = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("DataView");
            }
        }
        public XMLCFCCTranslationList()
        {
            var dataSet = new DataSet();
            dataSet.ReadXml(@"c:\file.xml");
            var cfccDataView = new DataView(dataSet.Tables[0]);
            DataView = cfccDataView;
        }
    }
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Translation xmlns="">
 <CFCCTranslation CFCC="A10" FUNC_CLASS="1" SPEED_CAT="5"  />
 <CFCCTranslation CFCC="A20" FUNC_CLASS="2" SPEED_CAT="5"  />
 <CFCCTranslation CFCC="A30" FUNC_CLASS="3" SPEED_CAT="5"  />
 <CFCCTranslation CFCC="A40" FUNC_CLASS="4" SPEED_CAT="5"  />
 <CFCCTranslation CFCC="A50" FUNC_CLASS="5" SPEED_CAT="5"  />
 <CFCCTranslation CFCC="A71" FUNC_CLASS="6" SPEED_CAT="5"  />
 <CFCCTranslation CFCC="B10" FUNC_CLASS="7" SPEED_CAT="5"  />
</Translation>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add DataCntext to view for it knew from where take data,

In your xaml.cs:

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly ViewModel viewModel = new ViewModel();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        DataContext = viewModel;
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```